# Import Processing pde into Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, jar, processing

I put some Processing jar files online for display. Because of Java update, I bought the code signing certificate to sign it. But now the jar files are still blocked because the output of Processing doesn't contain a MANIFEST.MF file:

[Java Query Answer](http://www.javaquery.com/2013/10/this-application-will-be-blocked-in.html)

It seems that I can't open the jar and insert a MANIFEST.MF with Eclipse. So I asked the programmer for the code and then I can add the mf like [this instuction](http://www.javaquery.com/2013/10/how-to-attach-manifestmf-file-in-jar.html). The project folder looks like:

```
project.pde
main.pde
button.pde
connection.pde
data[folder]
```

So now I follow [the Eclipse tutorial](http://processing.org/tutorials/eclipse/) and reach step 4 (Processing core.jar imported). The tutorial starts to write code. While how should I use the existing pde files to complete the work? Thanks!

Anyone who knows how to export Processing jar with MANIFEST.MF inside?
[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is really simple:

rename the jar file like myjar.zip, and then uncompress it. Under the new folder, go into the subfolder 'META-INF', and the file 'MANIFEST.MF' could be edited. The original info inside created by Processing usually says:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Created-By: Processing 1.5.1
Main-Class: myproj
```

we can add a few lines at the end:

```
Application-Library-Allowable-Codebase: *
Permissions: all-permissions
Codebase: *
```

then save the MANIFEST.MF, compress the whole folder, and rename the zip file as a jar file.
At last we can sign it with the certificate bought:

```
keytool -list -storetype pkcs12 -keystore cert.p12 -v | grep Alias
jarsigner -storetype pkcs12 -keystore cert.p12 proj.jar "cert.Alias" -tsa http://timestamp.comodoca.com/rfc3161 # I bought it from COMODO so the server link is like this
```

Upload it to the server and that's it.

Answer (score 0):

What version of Processing are you using? If you're using the latest, you can simply export your sketch as an application and then use [SvgExe](http://StaticVoidGames.com/SvgExe) to create a self-extracting runnable jar from Processing's output.

Or you can convert the code into a Java application, but that's not going to be as simple as importing the .pde files. Tutorial here: http://processing.org/tutorials/eclipse/

Comment: It's 2.1.2 while the SvgExe doesn't help. I added MANIFEST.MF in the external files tab and the output is still blocked by any browser.

Comment: I'm not sure what you meant by "doesn't help", since you have to export the files from Processing first, which it doesn't seem like you're doing. Simply adding a manifest won't do anything. You have to sign the jar.

Comment: I've signed it with my cert bought from COMODO. I followed the SvgExe instruction, combined my jar and the ProcessingLibrary.jar, and added the external MANIFEST.MF. Then I signed it. But it got blocked still. Now the problem I see is that the MANIFEST.MF must be inside my jar file, with the core.jar and other stuff when exported by Processing.

Comment: SvgExe adds a manifest. What error message do you get when it's blocked?

Comment: Just update my question with pictures. and also please visit the first link in my question, which is exactly the same issue.